# Retrieving Data from Soup in SmartStore shows error of function not found

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, smartstore, salesforce-mobile-app, salesforcesdk

I am using SmartStore provided by Salesforce Mobile SDK. At the time of retrieving data from Soup, it is showing error in “buildAllQuerySpec” is not a function. Tried with all other functions like: buildSmartQuerySpec, buildExactQuerySpec, but all functions are throwing same error.
[image]

Comment: Is the package name "smarstore" a typo?

Comment: @PhilW  you can ignore that please. Its a typing mistake. It is initialised with this name. I have double checked that. At the time of initialisation of mobilesdk parameter name is same.